# Azure Service Bus: Maximum execution time of message processing

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

**Short form of question**: We want throw an exception if time spent processing a message exceeds a given limit.

**Longer form of question**: We have several on-premise applications running as Windows Services, listening to messages on an Azure Service Bus Subscription, and among other things writing to Azure Blob Storage.

We have no problems with Service Bus or messaging in general. The service bus SDK seems to work perfectly.

The problem is in our application logic, after having received a message, we do lots of calls to external services, like SQL server. Oracle DB, blob storage, web APIs. We found that calls to blob storage suddenly started to hang, i.e. nothing happening, and this happened in several applications at the same time on the same machine. The *symptom* was that messages was not processed. As the *problem* was calls to blob storage not responding for some reason, the *solution* was to set a MaximumExecutionTime on the blob client. With this in place, we get a TaskCanceledException after the specified timeout, instead of just waiting forever (until restart of the application)

What I would like to know is if it possible to set a maximum execution time in the *SubsciptionClient*. Not for getting a message, but for our processing of the message. Or whether we would have to implement that in the callback (message handler) ourselves.

Comment: Well, I think the best idea to fix the root cause issue with blob connection. Other stuff is only a workaround

Comment: Yes, you are right, and we have fixed it. Our concern is that we have been running for years without MaximumExecutionTime without any problems, and suddenly it was a problem. We want to have a safeguard if something similar happens elsewhere in the application.

Comment: I had that problem before and we have implemented the solution in the `messageHandler` (client subscription) like you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the [OperationTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagingfactorysettings.operationtimeout?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessagingFactorySettings_OperationTimeout) property which specifies how long the messaging operation has to complete before timing out.

You can change the timeout using code like below:

```
MessagingFactorySettings settings = new MessagingFactorySettings { 
            OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0), 
            TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider("issuer", "sharedkey") };

var address = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("sb", "serviceNamespace", string.Empty);
var messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(address, settings);

return messagingFactory.CreateSubscriptionClient("subName");
```

Comment: I think this setting might be just for the operation of getting messages to the client, not for the custom processing of the message in the application. We are using the default value for this setting, and our applications have definitely been spending a lot more time on individual messages.